# Length for unique user ids (created in the range [0..N]) to be long enough for security purposes

Tags: performance, algorithm, security, validation

A person upon successful registration (enters email address, creates a password) receives a **generated** (so it's difficuilt to guess the previous or the next one) unique id - a big number from 0 to *N*. So, upon successful registration we have 3 things for each user: unique email, hash of the password and generated and unique id (an integer between 0 and *N*). Email, password hash and id are stored in the db.

The question is: How big should be *N* so that the probability to guess a valid id is no more than guessing a password (for any given email address). (The password can contain only capital and small letters, numbers, 8+ symbols, if that's important.) So, all I want is having ids that are too difficult to be guessed.

Suppose there should be no more than 10,000 registered users (depending on that number *N* depends). At least how many digits should contain a number *N* (0..*N* is a range for that long numbers to be unique) nowadays?

Is my algorythm good enough, fair, bad or very bad?
If I'm posting this question to the wrong thread, please let me know so the next time I will be OK.

P.S. That id from the db is applied to the SESSION variable when user logs in successfully.
All sql requests that extract personal data for the user, compare that id with that SESSION variable (so we now whose data to extract):

```
"SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Whether or not a specific length is good enough for security purposes is not generally answerable. It depends on how secure it has to be (so how vulnerable is your system if the number is guessed) and how big a number you can afford (Why make it smaller (and less secure) then necessary?). Although from your description I don't see why the id should be secure. Is there any way for the user to put a specific (not retreived from the db through normal means) id in the session? If not why not take an auto incremented id?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a hacker and I don't know too much about web-browser vulnerabilities. Tha's why I ask.    Could you please confirm that chance of (a very advanced user is able to change his session_id) is NULL? You could be right that chances are NULL, but I don't know the real answer (I'm a newbie).

Comment: It's almost certainly not null, however as long it's only stored in the db and the $_SESSION, it's safe by virtue of never leaving the server (assuming the db and the script are on the same server). Making the userid hard to guess in case the serverside data gets compromised seems silly, since it makes more sense to make the serverside data more secure. But no offense, designing secure systems (I assume login?) without knowing what one is doing is a BAD idea, so if you want to build a reasonable secure system I would really suggest reading as much as you can about that before trying.

Comment: Do you mean something like that:  http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Creating-a-Secure-PHP-Login-Script-59941/  (Simple and Secure PHP Login Script, including comments), when you say about readin gas much as you can?

Answer (score 2):

If you place effort into security, it should be focused on the password and not the user id.

Comment: I believe the verifying (email,password) (the hash stored instead of password) -vs.- verifying id is pretty much the same. I could be wrong that somebody in the world can compromise a SESSION id (now or later) to get results from db as a registered user. So, I don't want once a hacker generate id, it exist in the db. Am I wrong in my thoughts?

Comment: Even banks offer easy to remember user ids.  Also, browsers tend to show user ids on the screen while concealing passwords.  If you need more security, beef up the password scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be a certain size at all? Why don't you have a auto-incrementing unique id  and use that? Probably a primary key. Any SQL database should be able to manage that pretty much automatically provided you setup the table correctly.

Comment: I don't know too much and I'm not sure if a hacker can generate a session id. That's why I would prefer a unique ids, not incremented by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a numeral, you can use a string, something like a `UUID` should be pretty hard to guess.

```
>>> import uuid
>>> str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '')
'71dca6b8e3fb41708f93372171f53b9f'
>>>
```

Comment: Using numeric and a string is equivalent. As you can see, your string consists of 0..9abcdef. So it's 28+10=38 symbols, but it could take up to 256 for 1 byte. You use only ~10% of the reserved space. So, it's all the same about numeric or a string, the question is about how many bytes.

Comment: Yes, my point was that you can conveniently use *more chars than required*, instead of trying to figure out what the optimal number should be. (a numeral gives you `2 ** 64` options, a 32 char string gives you something which is `10 ** 37` times larger)

Comment: I thought 64 bytes is enough. But, recently I read SSL certificates with 1024 bits (128 bytes, right?) are not good anymore (at least 2048 bits is OK after 2010). Is 64 bytes enough in my question or 256 or even 1kb for id is needed?  But, I beleive it's a bit different things, right? That's how I decided to ask this question.    Thank you.

Comment: -1 for improper api use. UUIDs are not designed to be hard to guess, they're supposed to be unique. Some implementations are sufficiently unpredictable to be used for security, others are not. If you want something for security, use a cryptographically random number generator, if you want something unique use a UUID. If you want both, use a long sequence from the crypto PRNG.

Answer (score 1):

To make the number no easier to guess than the password, in the case that a paranoid user - or a program - chooses a password by generating it at true random, from amongst the set of all possible passwords, you need to number to be as large as min(number of possible passwords, number of possible password hashes). If you use the number without reference to the user name, you also need for it to be unique with high probability - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack.

In practice, computer systems have been known to use 128-bit or even 64-bit numbers as supposedly unguessable tokens. Another way to look at this is to consider how many guesses per second an attacker might be able to make, and considering how long it would take them to guess a 64-bit or 128-bit number with whatever probability makes you feel threatened. (The longer keys used with RSA are necessary because there are better ways of guessing an RSA private key than guessing numbers one by one).